# Proving the kernel is a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My professor proved that the kernel is a normal subgroup under a homomorphism f by saying. Let $h\in H$ 
by applying f to it
 $f(ghg^{-1})=f(g)f(h)f(g)^{-1}=e $

My question is how is this a proof that the kernel is normal. What is the reason we apply f to it ? By applying f dont we just prove that $f(ghg^{-1})$ is normal ?

Comment: Because by showing that, you know $ghg^{-1}$ is also in the kernel

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The argument goes as:

Let $f: G \to G_1$ be the homomorphism, and let $H = \operatorname{Ker}(f) = \{g \in G \; | \; f(g)=e \}$ be its kernel.

A subgroup is normal if it is invariant by conjugation. So fix an arbitrary element $h \in H$. For all $g \in G$, is it true that $ghg^{-1} \in H$ (which would mean that $H$ is indeed invariant by conjugation)?

And then he proves it as you have done above:
$$f(ghg^{-1}) = f(g)f(h)f(g^{-1}) = f(g)f(g)^{-1} = e$$

Comment: This just proves that it is normal if it is a subgroup, it doesn't prove that it is a subgroup, am I right?

Comment: Sure, but the OP's question was "how is this a proof that the kernel is normal". To prove that it is a subgroup just verify that it's closed w.r.t. inverse and group multiplication

Comment: Oh ok, I read the title, which says subgroup, but you have a point yes.

Comment: Yes, and maybe say that associativity is inherited from parent group, and identity maps to identity (so identity is part of kernel).

Comment: Perhaps this is obvious, but I can't see how to easily show the converse (ie. for all $g \in G$ and any $h \in H$, that $h \in gHg^{-1}$) in order to fully establish the equality $H = gHg^{-1}$ which is the definition of normal subgroup that I am working with. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @1729_SR Take $g=1$?

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't work with the requirement "for all $g$". As I think about it more I think that we can use that $g^{-1}hg \in H$ per the first direction of the proof that you gave.

Comment: Take $g^{-1}$ instead of $g$ then? Sorry I don't get the meaning of "converse" here.

Comment: No worries -- I think I understand now. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help!

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 the question is that the answer provided has only shown $g\text{ker}\phi g^{-1}\subset \text{ker}\phi,$ rather than the desired set equality. Now we must show that $\text{ker}\phi\subset g\text{ker}\phi g^{-1} \forall g\in G$. I do not know how to show this.

Comment: Nevermind, equality isn't the correct condition, see eg https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_is_Normal_iff_Contains_Conjugate_Elements. @EE18: we must both be using a source that states the theorem wrong.

Comment: It's been a while but I was using the text by Szekeres here. @UtterImposter

Answer (score 2):

We have a group $G$ and a group homomorphism $f$ that takes elements from $G$. We also have $\ker(f) = H$. We want to show that $H$ is normal. One way of describing "$H$ is normal" is that given arbitrary $h\in H$ and $g\in G$, we must have $ghg^{-1}\in H$. By definition of $H$, $ghg^{-1}\in H$ is equivalent to $f(ghg^{-1}) = e$. So that is what we check for.